# How to prevent text from wrapping under inserted element?

Tags: html, css, layout, word-wrap

I am working with an existing markup little of which I can change (Scenario 1)
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anunay/fWXyd).

```css
.container {
  width: 340px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.title a {
  font: 32px/normal 'Segoe UI Light', Arial;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #606060;
}

span.bb {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="title">
    <!-- following span tag is added at runtime -->
    <span class="bb"></span>
    <a href="http://test.com" target="_blank">  
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  
                adipisicing elit  
            </a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

I want to insert a fixed sized span tag which works great as long the existing text fits on a single line (Scenario 2). If the existing text spans multiple lines, it wraps under the span tag that I inserted (Scenario 3).

I want to prevent text from wrapping under the span tag and want the subsequent lines to align with the first word of the sentence.

I tried couple of approaches, but didn't get the solution quite right without loosing the wrapping ability or breaking existing scenarios.

I would prefer a CSS solution for fixing this layout problem.

Comment: did you try "no-wrap"

Answer (score 3):

I got this working by adding following additional styles

```
span.bb {
    float:left;
}

span.bb + a {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 42px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anunay/3bqLq/